# Rotating around a non origin point

Tags: c++, directx, software-engineering

I've been looking around the forums for some answers to the question I have. I've found some answer that seem to help but nothing that answers my specific question. That question being how to rotate an object in world space around a non origin point.

I have a grappling hook that I am trying to implement inside of a game I am making for a final college project. This grappling hook collides with another object in world space and I then want the player to rotate around this point as if a rope were present.

I have the point at which the grapple collides the point at which the player is located and the origin. I tried the standard translate to the origin rotate and translate back and that did not work.

This is being done in DirectX 9 and it is a C++ game. Any  help you could offer would be greatly appreciated. If you need anymore info please ask.

Edit: I should also add that we are doing a vector based storage for this setup. So I store the matrices in vectors(i.e Forward,Direction,Right,Position) and build the matrices on the fly

```
void CSpatialFrame::RotateAbout(D3DXVECTOR3 _Point, float _fDegPitch, float _fDegYaw, float _fDegRoll)
{
    D3DXMATRIX RotationMatrix;
    D3DXMatrixRotationYawPitchRoll(&RotationMatrix, D3DXToRadian( _fDegYaw ), D3DXToRadian( _fDegPitch ), D3DXToRadian( _fDegRoll ));
    D3DXVECTOR3 playerPos = m_Position;
    m_Position = _Point;

    D3DXMATRIX PlayerMatrix;

    PlayerMatrix._11 = m_RightVector.x;
    PlayerMatrix._21 = m_RightVector.y;
    PlayerMatrix._31 = m_RightVector.z;

    PlayerMatrix._12 = m_UpVector.x;
    PlayerMatrix._22 = m_UpVector.y;
    PlayerMatrix._32 = m_UpVector.z;

    PlayerMatrix._13 = m_DirectionVector.x;
    PlayerMatrix._23 = m_DirectionVector.y;
    PlayerMatrix._33 = m_DirectionVector.z;

    PlayerMatrix._14 = m_Position.x;
    PlayerMatrix._24 = m_Position.y;
    PlayerMatrix._34 = m_Position.z;

    D3DXMatrixTranslation(&PlayerMatrix, _Point.x, _Point.y, _Point.z);

    //D3DXMatrixTranslation(&PlayerMatrix, m_Position.x, m_Position.y, m_Position.z);

    D3DXMatrixMultiply(&PlayerMatrix, &RotationMatrix, &PlayerMatrix);

    //D3DXMatrixTranslation(&PlayerMatrix, _Point.x, _Point.y, _Point.z);

    m_RightVector.x = PlayerMatrix._11;
    m_RightVector.y = PlayerMatrix._21;
    m_RightVector.z = PlayerMatrix._31;

    m_UpVector.x = PlayerMatrix._12;
    m_UpVector.y = PlayerMatrix._22;
    m_UpVector.z = PlayerMatrix._32;

    m_DirectionVector.x = PlayerMatrix._13;
    m_DirectionVector.y = PlayerMatrix._23;
    m_DirectionVector.z = PlayerMatrix._33;

    m_Position.x = PlayerMatrix._14;
    m_Position.x = PlayerMatrix._24;
    m_Position.x = PlayerMatrix._34;
}
```

Comment: Translating to the origin, rotating and translating it back to the point were it was is definitely the way to go. Please, post some code and we can probably have a look at it.

Answer (score 5):

Translate the character so that the rotation point is the origin.  Perform the rotation.  Translate back.

Pretty standard linear algebra an affine transformation stuff.  You might consider browsing for an intro to linear algebra for game programmers article and find one that you like.  I don't know of any particularly excellent ones myself, sorry.  Quite sure they're out there though.